# Applying responsive-nav to two different navigations

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, selector

I have this HTML code and using responsive-nav.js to make responsive navigation

```
<nav class="nav-collapse first pull-left">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

          </ul>
        </nav>

        <nav class="nav-collapse second pull-right">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">New</a></li>

          </ul>
        </nav>

<script src="responsive-nav.js"></script>
<script>
  var nav = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse.first, .nav-collapse.second");
</script>
```

How may I apply responsive-nav on both?

Answer (score 0):

This is how the script selects the element by the specified selector:

```
    this.wrapperEl = el.replace("#", "");
    if (document.getElementById(this.wrapperEl)) {
      this.wrapper = document.getElementById(this.wrapperEl);
    } else if (document.querySelector(this.wrapperEl)) {
      this.wrapper = document.querySelector(this.wrapperEl);
    } else {
      // If el doesn't exists, stop here.
      throw new Error("The nav element you are trying to select doesn't exist");
    }
```

So as you see, it is not possible to select two elements at once, like jQuery does. You need to call `responsiveNav` twice.